# Error when calling Cognitive Face API, "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ldm.models'; 'ldm' is not a package"

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror, stable-diffusion

Part 1:

I'm using the Cognitive Face API in my Python project for image editing, but I'm encountering an error when running my script
`python3 edit_cli.py --input imgs/example.jpg --output imgs/output.jpg --edit "turn him into a cyborg"`.
The error message I receive is:
`Error when calling Cognitive Face API: status_code: 401, code: 401, message: Access denied due to invalid subscription key or wrong API endpoint. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription and use a correct regional API endpoint for your resource.`
I've double-checked my subscription key and the API endpoint, and both seem to be correct. However, the error persists.

I'm seeking advice on how to troubleshoot this issue and ensure my Face API calls are successful. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Part 2:

I'm working on a Python project and facing an issue with module imports. When executing my image editing script
`python3 edit_cli.py --input imgs/example.jpg --output imgs/output.jpg --edit "turn him into a cyborg"`,
I encounter the error
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ldm.models'; 'ldm' is not a package`.
The `ldm.models` module does exist, but it's under `stable_diffusion`. I tried updating the import statement to `import stable_diffusion.ldm.models`, but the error persists. The parent directory of `stable_diffusion` is included in my `PYTHONPATH`. The directory structure is as follows: my_project_folder -> stable_diffusion -> ldm -> models -> some_model.py. Even when trying to import with `from stable_diffusion.ldm.models import SomeClass`, the error still occurs.

Any assistance in understanding and rectifying this import error would be greatly appreciated.